# How can i detect browser using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried all the solutions from the below link but I couldn't make it work. [How can I detect browser type using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352522/how-can-i-detect-browser-type-using-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 
    if($.browser.chrome){
        alert(1);
             //this work well
    }
            else if(//the browser is IE){alert(2);}
            else if(//the browser is Firefox){alert(3);}

 )};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to know the browser? And posting the exact same question as in another, already answered, question cries for a duplicate-closure. Instead show your actual code which doesn't work and we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

$.browser is depreciated so you may have to use migrate plugin as mentioned in:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Checking browser may not be relevant anymore, have a look at:
http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

You may use window.navigator.appVersion if you want to still detect browser.

I could see window.navigator.appVersion returned below to me:

IE: 
"5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; GWX:RESERVED; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Mozilla:
"5.0 (Windows)"

Chrome:
"5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"