# Trigger click based on browser jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a condition I want to do something based on browser, as some of things are not working in IE, I would like to do something except for the Chrome.

Like below, I have siple click event and showing DIV, but instead in

```
$('.testBtn').click(function(){
    //for Chrome only
    $(".divContent").show();
    //for IE and Mozilla
    $(".divContent").show(
        function(){
        //do something
        });
});

<div class="divContent" style="display:none">
    This is Test content
</div>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: May be you can find this useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352522/how-can-i-detect-browser-type-using-jquery

Answer (score -1):

You can get the user-agent send by the browser with the function :

```
navigator.userAgent
```

Then you'll just have to make condition depending on the result. See doc [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)