# Using jQuery to detect browser

Tags: jquery, parsing, navigator, browser-detection

### Question:

I can predict both **Chrome** and **Safari** using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    /* Detect Chrome */
    if($.browser.chrome){
        alert("You are using Chrome!");
        
        /* if it is Chrome then jQuery thinks it's 
           Safari so we have to tell it isn't */
        $.browser.safari = false;
    }

    /* Detect Safari */
    if($.browser.safari){
        alert("You are using Safari!");
    }

});
```

This code, but I've no idea, how I can know about other browsers like

> Opera, UC browser or IE !

### Parse method

I can extract
**navigator.userAgent.indexOf();** using parse method but if every time I've to get **-1** then what's the purpose of doing it? How can I use this information?

Comment: Why are you attempting browser detection, you should really be using feature detection for features you are trying to use

Comment: This may help you: [How can I detect browser type using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352522/how-can-i-detect-browser-type-using-jquery)

Comment: another possibility is: [bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser)

Comment: The string "Chrome" is in the user agent string of almost all major browsers; see http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Comment: Thanks Heretic monkey, I got your point!